# the vulnerability of (a/the/no article) domestic market

Tags: nouns, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, modifiers

The sentence is:

> One of the limitations of liberalization is that it increases the vulnerability of (a/the/no article) domestic market to foreign shocks.

Am I free to use either 'the', 'a', or no article in this sentence? If one is better than the others, please explain why.

And is 'domestic market' together a noun or only 'domestic' is a noun?

Answer (score 0):

> One of the limitations of liberalization is that it increases the
>   vulnerability of the domestic market to foreign shocks.

*Domestic* is an adjective.

*Market* is a noun.

Comment: Can I take liberties to use 'a' or no article ? Why only 'the' is used here ?

Comment: You could, but it would sound awkward.

Comment: @user227275: Most likely your cited example is talking about *one particular* domestic market. If it's a more general statement about the effects of "liberalization" in different markets across the world, the indefinite article could feasibly be used "naturally" *(the vulnerability of **a** domestic market)*, but in that context most writers would simply pluralise ***markets*** anyway. Also note that singular with the definite article could feasibly be used even in that "general" case (referencing ***any one**,* treated as ***the** one from whose perspective all other markets are "foreign"*).